# Mutating while using the map_dfr function

Tags: r, dictionary, mutate

From the baseballr package

```
batting_orders <- map_dfr(games, get_batting_orders)
```

So the games is a vector for every unique game, and I was wondering if I could attach each game ID that I'm giving as an input in map_dfr, to the outputting dataframe.

I tried to create a function, but it wont take a vector as an input.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `map_dfr` has an argument for it: `.id`; you just have to give an name and the input value is automatically added to your data.frame:

```
batting_orders <- map_dfr(games, get_batting_orders, .id = "game_id")
```